# Should the Writing stackexchange be added to the list of sites for migration?

Tags: discussion, migration

I've done a vote-close on a number of bugs where I would have liked to mark it as needing to be migrated to https://writing.stackexchange.com, but the only migration destination location available in the UI is this meta site.

Should/can Writing be added as a suggested destination for migration?

[image]

Comment: I don't think enough posts are migrated to make this worthwhile. There were only two in the last year. (PS I am a Writing mod.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## No

Migration has a high bar to clear:

1. The question to be migrated has to be *off-topic* for this site.
2. The question to be migrated has to be *on-topic* on the target site.
3. The question to be migrated should be of high quality and ready to be migrated to the target site. Bad question should ***not*** be migrated. We do not want to just shuffle them to be somebody else's problem.

This criteria thus requires familiarity with the target site to be able to make an informed decision.

This is a lot to ask from five different users. They should all individually be familiar with the target site's rules and policies.

I often see people recommending a different site *without* actually knowing enough about it. I think having a special migration path should not be given to regular users. With the exception of migration to the per-site Meta. Migrations should be an exception and as such [I concur with L.Dutch](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9748) that it should be left to moderators. They are the exception handlers around here anyway.

To clarify: I do agree that some migrations can successfully be handled by the community. However, I feat that they would not be the majority of migrations. Migrations in general are quite rare, *good* migrations rarer than that. Having them as an exceptional case seems the most prudent choice to me.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that everyone should be able to migrate posts, I'm just suggesting that in the UI for close votes, *suggesting* migration to the writing stack exchange would be a good option to offer.

Comment: The close vote reasons under "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" are all migration paths. If enough users vote for them, then the question is automatically migrated. It's not just a suggestion.

Comment: Ah! Good to know. Makes sense, then. My apologies for not understanding that aspect of it.

Comment: I concur that care must be taken when it comes to migration. I've often had to slomo shout *NNNNNNOOOOOO!!!!!!* when someone on SciFi/F suggests a migration to here. Simply because the question isn't a good fit and people who are accustomed to one forum may not be familiar with the rules and traditions of the other.  We can always flag a question for moderator attention and we can always suggest question migration in the flag, if migration is warranted.

Answer (score 8):

Considering how annoying it is for us when whatever question not fitting another SE community gets dumped on Worldbuilding, personally I would not like returning the annoyance.

I would rather leave the choice of the target for migration to moderators, who have the means for prior alignment with the receiving side. Normal users would still flag the post suggesting migration.